# Paging in mvc3 with html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchByOperator(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string operatorname,int page=1)
{
   List<CRBT_CALLS> operator_list = new List<CRBT_CALLS>();
   using (crbt_onwebEntities dbcontext = new crbt_onwebEntities())

   operator_list = (from z in dbcontext.CRBT_CALLS
                    where z.DOWNLOAD_TIME > fromdate && z.DOWNLOAD_TIME < todate && z.OPERATOR == operatorname
                    select z).OrderBy(x => x.DOWNLOAD_TIME).ToList();
```

This is my view page. When I am clicking on 1, 2, 3, and paging link, it is showing:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'fromdate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SearchByOperator(System.DateTime, System.DateTime, System.String, Int32)' in 'mvclogin.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error page, it looks like you are not including the proper parameters up to your Action in the paging links. The error message says that the `fromDate` parameter is not included, and since this is a required parameter and no other Actions match your route, an error is thrown.

You should look to either include all of the parameter info (fromdate, todate, etc) in the querystring of your paging links, or redefine your Action to allow for these parameters to be optional.